# [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]. dont know what the problem is

Tags: c, pointers, incompatibletypeerror

I am not able to find where it went wrong. When I run the program, it shows "access denied".

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char arr[4][40] =
    { "array of c string",
        "is fun to use",
        "make sure to properly",
        "tell the array size"
    };
char *p = arr;  /*Char-4-eg-Find-the-output.c:10:11: warning: initialization of 'char *' from 
incompatible pointer type 'char (*)[40]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]*/
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        printf("%c",*p );
        p++;
   }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output? What should your program do?

Comment: The program should be fine because accessing bytes in objects via `char*` is allowed and `arr` should be more than 100 bytes. "access denied" probably means your anti-virus software didn't like your creation. Add a cast to elimiinate the warning: `char *p = (char*)arr;`

Comment: It means that `char *p = arr;` is nonsensical, simple as that. I guess you meant to point at the first item of the first array? That would be `char *p = &arr[0][0];`

Answer (score 5):

Array designators used in expressions with rare exceptions are converted to pointers to their first elements.

So in this declaration

```
char *p = arr;
```

the array designator `arr` is converted to a pointer to its first element. Elements of the array `arr` have the type `char[40]`. So a pointer to an object of this type has the type `char( * )[40]`.

However the initialized pointer has the type `char *`. And there is no implicit conversion from the type `char ( * )[40]` to the type `char *`. So the compiler issues a message.

Either you need to use casting like

```
char *p = ( char * )arr;
```

or to write

```
char *p = arr[0];
```

or

```
char *p = &arr[0][0];
```

If you want to output the array of strings as one sentence you could write for example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 40 };
    
    char arr[][N] =
    { 
        "array of c string",
        "is fun to use",
        "make sure to properly",
        "tell the array size"
    };
    

    for ( char ( *p )[N] = arr; p != arr + sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( *arr ); ++p )
    {
        if ( p != arr ) putchar( ' ' );
        printf( "%s", *p );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
array of c string is fun to use make sure to properly tell the array size
```

Comment: In this case the warning can be silenced with `char *p = arr[0];` or `char *p = &arr[0][0];`,, but I'm not sure what OP is trying to do with the code snipped he posted.

Comment: @icebp it can be silenced with `char (*p)[40] = arr;` too

Answer (score 1):

Change `char *p = arr;` to `char *p = &arr[0][0];`.

Comment: That's just an excerp of another (good) answer, without any explanations...

Comment: @manuell Sorry, I also have to study for exams in my high school, so I didn't have so much time to explain it elaborately, but I ofcourse did not excerpt it from the other answers.